# Cannot append BR tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, flexbox

So, I am taking data from a textarea separated by comma, converting to an array and appending them all to a div with class `chars`. I want it such that the div will only have 5 children appended per row.

My JS code:

```
var board = document.getElementsByClassName("chars")[0];
var input = document.getElementById("charInput").value; 

function appendthem(){
    
    input = input.replace(/ /g,'')
    var array= input.split(",");

    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        var elem = document.createElement("p");
        var textnode  = document.createTextNode(array[i]);
        elem.appendChild(textnode);
        board.appendChild(elem);     
    }
}
```

I don't know if the CSS will have a role to play here. But the CSS of my div (chars) is:

```
.chars{
    padding: 20px 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

I tried but did not work:

```
var br = document.createElement("br");
        if( (i+1)%5 ==0 ){
            board.appendChild(br);   
        }
        else{
            board.appendChild(elem);    
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) to split into 5 columns:

```js
var board = document.getElementsByClassName("chars")[0];
var input = 'test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test'; 

(function appendthem()
{
    input = input.replace(/ /g,'')
    var array= input.split(",");

    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        var elem = document.createElement("p");
        var textnode  = document.createTextNode(array[i]);
        elem.appendChild(textnode);
        board.appendChild(elem);     
    }
})()
```

```css
.chars {
    padding: 20px 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="chars"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using grid template on all your child elements using just css

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
```

If you need to add spacing between the elements just include

```
grid-column-gap: 10px;
```

Just note, this does not have the same effect as flex and you will need to make different screen size adjustments as this isn't the best responsive setup.

Comment: Thank you! Similar to Mihai's answer. Works.